# Is lightning is replacement for visualforce

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning

I am little confused in lightning.
is lightning is replacement of visualforce or it is only use for salesforce1
does it mean going forward most of the business customization  will be done by lightning components instead of vf?
Please explain